# Using multi-dimensional rewards to prevent intermediary reward bias

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning, ai-design, rewards, reward-functions

I came up with a new type of reward scheme to avoid intermediary reward bias and am unable to find any literature references to it. My questions are

1. Is this novel?
2. Is this useful?

The approach is as follows:

I maintain two sets of rewards that are stored in a tuple - intermediary and end-goal rewards. During the initial training phase, the agent receives feedback from both sets. It then simply uses sum(rewards) to make any decisions and updates where normally the one-dimensional reward would be used.

Once the agent reaches a certain level of proficiency (i.e., it can find the end state in a reasonable amount of time), I remove the intermediary rewards from the agent's model of state values. Since these rewards are cleanly separated, I can do this without affecting my end-state reward knowledge.

Once this is done, the agent will be optimized to the end-state reward only. A short training period can be used to push the agent to explore states that have particularly high end-state reward values but don't have adequate intermediary reward values. This training should take much less time than traditionally after removing the intermediary rewards since the agent's knowledge of the rewards of each state doesn't need to be retrained.

Has a similar multi-dimensional reward technique been explored or documented before?